# Improving RAM performance for Photoshop?

Tags: memory, performance, adobe-photoshop

I'm upgrading the amount of RAM in my machine, before I purchase it, I thought I would ask does the RAM's speed have much, if any benefit for applications like Photoshop and video editing? i.e. 1333Mhz vs 2400Mhz I've tried Googling the issue, but all the results I get are from gaming forums, which aren't of much help.

Comment: Could you actually measure how much RAM you are using when the system slows down? It might indeed have run out of free memory, or it could be something else. Just adding RAM will not help in the case it is something else.

Comment: It would very little different if your running into performance problems with 12GB of memory.  I assume your using the 64-bit version of Photoshop?

Comment: @LukeJonGibson what Hennes and Ramhound is saying is you may have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You think that increasing your ram speed will solve your problem (`X`) so you are focusing on that, we are just saying take a step back and look at the bigger picture and find the root of the problem (`Y`) (like maybe Photoshop is not utilizing the 12 gigs you are giving it) and give you a even better solution.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to find the root cause of a problem. But I never said I had a problem. I know exactly what is causing the slow down and how to fix it. My only question was as I am already upgrading my RAM, would getting higher speed RAM be of any benefit? Cheers

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear, what I'm actually after. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory speed does not affect Photoshop performance much. There might be some performance gain, but it is not significant, as in, you don't actually feel the improvement. I have tried using 1600MHz and 2400MHz, but I can't feel the difference in Photoshop.

Which ver of Photoshop are you using - 32-bit or 64-bit? According to Adobe, Photoshop could benefit more than 4GB of RAMs only if both Photoshop and the OS are 64-bit versions.

Comment: I am using 64 bit Photoshop, in task manager it uses 10GB of Ram the maximum amount allowed by the Photoshop performance options.